# How to get inner html of custom directive?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a directive for html like this

```
<div my-modal my-modal-id="test">
    <div class="inner">Hello Inner</div>
</div>
```

want to generate html from above to something like

```
<div id="test">
    <h1>My Heading</h1>
    <div class="b">
        Hello Inner
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
.directive('myModal', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            myModalId: '@'            
        },
        compile: function(tEle, tAttrs, transcludeFn) {
            //what to do here?
            //I want to get div.inner of the original html
        },
        template: '<div id="{{myModalId}}">' +
            '<h1>My Heading</h1>' +
            '<div class="b"></div>' +
            '</div>'
    }
});
```

Comment: tEle is the generated template, i.e. whats inside template: but I want the original element on which directive was applied.

Comment: is $(tEle.context) the right way to get the original element?

Comment: Have you looked into the `transclude` property of the Directive Definition Object ? BTW, using `transcludeFn` in **compile** is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can use a template, it seems to overwrite the existing html before `compile` is called.  Grabbing the HTML and replacing it yourself seems to work ([***plnkr***](http://plnkr.co/edit/mJhnzaDcLCA414wK0pPH?p=preview)):

```
.directive('content', function($compile) {
  var dir = {
    restrict: 'E',
    xemplate: '<div id="{{myModalId}}">' +
      '<h1>My Heading</h1>' +
      '<div class="b">Original:<br/><pre>{{original}}</pre></div>' +
      '</div>',
    compile: function(element, attrs, linker) {
      var original = element.html(); // grab original
      element.html(dir.xemplate); // set template html manually
      return function(scope, element, attributes) {
        scope.original = original
      }
    }
  };
  return dir;
});
```